# AJAX shopping cart for ASP.NET site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, shopping-cart

Could you please recommend me good free solution for AJAX shopping cart for ASP.NET site.

Actually I already have my own shopping cart on my site, but it works with redirects like you clicked on "Add To Cart" button, it sends the page (postback) to server and redirect me to ShowCart page where added item is there. I need some javascript to not redirect to shopping cart page.

It should work like: click on "Add To Cart" button, page not reload or redirect, ajax banner appear at the top of the page and shows all items (include just added) in the shopping cart.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is exactly what I searched: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/jbasket/sliding-basket/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the eCommerce section](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/categories.aspx?category=eCommerce) of the windows web applications gallery.

Answer (score 1):

[NopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com) is very good, the last edition is web forms and the most recent version is MVC.

Comment: nopCommerce requires an ASP.Net MVC project, unless one uses an older version (1.9 and previous).  I know.  I tried downloading and ran into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these:

[Vista Cart](http://www.guruasp.net/)

[dashcommerce](http://dashcommerce.org/)

Comment: Vista Cart (I wrote them just now asking about the issue) apparently lacks coupon support.  It has a great interface and supports basic C# ASP.Net (non MVC).  It also has not come out with an upgrade since February 2012 and supports .Net 3.5 and VS2010.  DashCommerce has other issues, namely no support and more importantly runs into installation problems.  I will post separately for that.